# Modeling with MongoDB and Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a simple app which lists tour guides and reviews left by users about each guide. Any user can give be a guide and can give reviews. My scheme for a user is:

```
var User = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    firstName: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    lastName: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true}   
    isGuide: Boolean,
    rating: {type: Number, "default": 0, min: 0, max: 5},
    reviews: [reviewSchema]
});


var Review = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    author: {type: String, required: true},//contatenation of firstName and lastName of user that wrote review
    rating: {type: Number, required: true, min: 0, max: 5},
    reviewText: {type: String, required: true},
    createdOn: {type: Date, "default": Date.now}
});

mongoose.model('User', User);
```

I want to be able to:

1/ show a guide and all that guide's reviews
2/ show all a user's reviews
3/ show all guides a user has reviewed

I think my schema above is fine for 1. But is it suitable for 2 and 3? Am I understanding the MonboDB philosophy correctly?

Comment: The philosophy of most general NoSQL solutuions to to "model it how you actually use it". So how do you actually use it? Do you read more related data at once? Do you update related things or things separately? This is the basics of "referencing" to "embedding" which the latter is a native concept to NoSQL solutions such as MongoDB rather than an API implementation such as mongoose. That should give you some food for thought at least, if you don't think that answers your question. There is plenty of reading out there on the topic.

Comment: Thanks. I believe my schema is correct as primarily reviews belong to guides. So embedding reviews to User schema whilst caching the firatName and lastName would appear to be correct approach as nothing else we need to be fetched.

Comment: It's not a matter of "correct" and I was not critiquing you in such a way though you seem to have interpreted so. It's really all about "how you use it" as I said. There is "no best way" but only "the best way for you". Only you and your code usage can determine which is best.